# Determine whether a point is inside a cube using only distance queries

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a 3D distance field that contains the distance to points in a grid (e.g. an [ESDF or TSDF](https://rss16-representations.mit.edu/papers/BeyondGeometryRSSW16_2_CameraReadySubmission_Oleynikova.pdf)), I want to efficiently check whether a cube at an arbitrary orientation contains a point.

A straightforward approach is to perform raytracing to identify which cells are contained inside of the cube and check if any of those cells have 0 distance. This solution is unsatisfying because it throws away the distance information and is tightly coupled to the underlying ESDF via raytracing. It seems like we should be able to solve this problem more generally using the distance information and the resolution parameter.

One could imagine a more sophisticated approach which first checks the distance from the center of the cube to a point - if the value is large enough we know the cube is empty, or if it is small enough we know there is a point inside the cube. If the value is somewhere in between, we could recursively check the ambiguous regions. Because the distance function is discretized this algorithm should eventually terminate if the bookkeeping is done properly during the search.

Of course the devil is in the details and that is why I'm asking this question. What is the most efficient method to identify if there is a point inside the cube? If this is a classical problem, what is it called?